# Set the Div at the end of user window screen

Tags: jquery, css

what am trying to do just to make this div displayed at the end of the user screen to display some news , it should be straight forward job , actually the div suddenly disappear from the page ! if i zoom in or zoom out the browser its just come at the position that it should be !! what is the problem ?

```
<style>
        #news_div{

            background-color: red;
            width:800px;
            height:40px;
            padding:0;
            margin:0;
            position: fixed;
            z-index: 1;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
<div id="news_div"> The news </div>
<script>
$( function(){

    $("#news_div").offset({

        top : $(window).height(),

    })});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, the `top` property specifies the distance of the top of your `DIV` to the top if the window. If you set the `DIV`'s `top` property to window's `top` your `DIV` is exactly outside the window or outside the visible area.

You have to subtract the height of the `DIV` itself to get it to the bottom:

```
$(function() {
    $("#news_div").offset({
        top : $(window).height() -$('#news_div').height()
    })
});
```